# I Cannot Create New Category

Tags: categories

For some reason I can't add new category. I changed the browser and even tried on my iPod Touch but it still did not do anything. It did not show any error message, No Nothing. It's like the new category wasn't even there.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers! Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your question to make answers possible.

Answer (score 1):

Tom's answer looks really useful to me.

I'd also suggest the standard WP troubleshooting tip of turning off plugins and seeing if you are able to add categories when your plugins are off.  If so, turn plugins back on one by one and see if you can figure out which plugin is the "culprit".

Sometimes it's a plugin that is intentionally doing something to manage your categories for you, for instance, and sometimes it's a plugin that's just causing a glitch.  Often you'll be able to get help from the developer if it's a true conflict and not a feature.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot to go on at this point, so here are some general considerations. Why you might not be able to add categories;

- Maybe you're [just not doing it right](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Posts#Descriptions_of_Post_Fields)? (I don't know how much experience you have with WordPress?) Here's a video: http://wordpress.tv/2009/01/14/adding-categories-and-tags-to-your-posts/
- You need to have permission to [manage categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#manage_categories) in order to add new ones. Maybe your current role doesn't have this permission (even though it can edit posts)
- See if you can manually add the category using Posts > Categories rather than adding them inside your post directly